# Using Authorization to keep Users from accessing unrelated Data in a REST API

Tags: database, rest, api, authorization, jwt

First, let me quickly describe a very basic layout of my application:
I have several companies that all have their own users. Some users have more access to actions than others. Users with more access can create Dashboards, which in turn may contain either Tables (with Rows and Columns, additional Data, etc.), or Charts, which have Subcharts, more Data, etc. It gets quite deep pretty quickly. There are further parts of the application, but this should suffice as a broad example.

The problem I have come across is connected to Authorization. I am using JWT's to handle most stuff on a User and Company Level (i.e. the User is part of that Company, so he can make changes to that Company based on his access level). 
However, once we reach the deeper Tables in the Database, such as adding and editing the rows of a Table, I'd have to traverse all the way up the Table-Chain to identify which Company that Row belongs to. This feels really inefficient to me, especially when it comes to many-to-many relationships, and making any kinds of changes to the Data-Structure would be a nightmare. Another idea would be to add a Column for the CompanyID to each Table, but that defeats the purpose of relational data in my opinion.

Is there a best-practice to deal with this type of issue? I have looked online but haven't been very successful in finding a solution, possibly in part because I suck at putting the issue in a few simple words, but either way I'd really appreciate any kind of advice you guys would be able to offer!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's "best practice", but here's how I approach it:

1. My REST API endpoints let me know exactly what the caller is trying to do.
2. My session management (e.g., the JWT and related user data) is managed in the REST API layer.  When a request comes in, I load the user and company data for that user.  This assumes the JWT doesn't keep access rights - just user ids.  This allows the access rights to change during the lifetime of the JWT.  Useful for long-lived tokens used in some applications.
3. Given (1) and (2), the code can determine if the user has the rights to run the request.

Once the code gets past step (3), it doesn't worry any longer about access rights.  In fact, the lower layers of the code don't need any access rights logic.

Yes, in some cases the code has to traverse up the tree from the target table/row to find out what user/company owned it.  For that, I recommend custom queries so you only have to hit the database the one time to determine ownership.  "Does company/user A own record X?"  And if the app is beating up the database around that query, you could always cache the answer locally.  Or add the company/user id column.

Note that adding the company id column doesn't break the relational properties of the database.  It may "de-normalize" it, sure.  But that's just one of the trade-offs we make as developers to get the performance required.  I wouldn't sweat it if that's a better solution given your data model.

Regarding many-to-many relationships, I would assume that if the user had access to one element, the others it links to are owned by the same user/company or they aren't things this code would modify in the given call.  Of course, I don't know your application, but in my experience that tends to be true.  So the one access check should apply.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! After thinking on it for a while on my way home yesterday, I've decided to use a combination of these options by following these patterns: The Company gets an additional 'AuthorizationKey' that is needed to allow changing any entries that belong to it, connected via the 'AuthorizationLock' on those entities, which have the same value. When logging in, the User gets the AuthorizationKey and compares it to the lock each time they're trying to do anything requiring Authorization. Technically, I simply went around around giving everything the CompanyID column by adding...

Comment: Another ID (the SecurityKey) to the Company Table and comparing that instead of the actual ID, but this gives it a more purpose-driven feel and allows it to be exposed via an interface. I.e. all IAuthorizationKey interfaces must provide the key, and all IAuthorizationLock interfaces must have a lock.

Comment: Glad to help.  I am actually kicking around the idea of a database model that would handle this type of problem by design.  Authorization built in to the data model and managed by the database engine.  This type of project seems like an ideal use of the technology, so the question caught my eye.  I am thinking more along the lines of key pairs with signed authorization access, but the same basic idea.

Comment: Interesting project. Good luck with that!